# How to print only the Content of the Table and Hide rest of the things

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I click on the Print Button, It should open print dialog box and Print only the Table Content and Hide rest of the things, but now it is printing all the other content also like pagination , date everything...
But it needs to print only the table Content.
How can I modify my code to Print only the tables data and hide rest of the things, without opening in a new tab..

Here is my code

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import axios from "axios";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import "jspdf-autotable";

const ButtonUsage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [showTable, setShowTable] = useState(false);
  const recordsPerPage = 10;
  const pagesToShow = 5;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showTable) {
      getProductData();
    }
  }, [showTable]);

  const getProductData = () => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((res) => {
      setData(res.data);
    });
  };

  // Calculate the maximum number of pages based on the data
  const maxPages =
    data && data.length > 0 ? Math.ceil(data.length / recordsPerPage) : 1;

  // Change page
  const paginate = (pageNumber) => {
    setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
  };

  // Function to download the current page as a PDF
  const downloadAsPDF = () => {
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.autoTable({
      head: [["userId", "id", "title", "completed"]],
      body: data
        .slice((currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage, currentPage * recordsPerPage)
        .map((row) => [
          row.userId,
          row.id,
          row.title,
          row.completed ? "Yes" : "No",
        ]),
    });

    doc.save("table.pdf");
  };

  // Function to open the browser's print dialog
  const printTable = () => {
    window.print();
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => setShowTable(true)}>
        Get Data
      </Button>

      {showTable && data && data.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table
              sx={{ minWidth: 650 }}
              size="small"
              aria-label="a dense table"
            >
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell>userId</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>id</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>title</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>completed</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {data
                  .slice(
                    (currentPage - 1) * recordsPerPage,
                    currentPage * recordsPerPage
                  )
                  .map((row) => (
                    <TableRow
                      key={row.id}
                      sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
                    >
                      <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                        {row.userId}
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.userId}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.id}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.title}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{row.completed ? "Yes" : "No"}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </TableContainer>
          <div className="pagination">
            <button onClick={() => paginate(1)} disabled={currentPage === 1}>
              First
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => paginate(currentPage - 1)}
              disabled={currentPage === 1}
            >
              Previous
            </button>
            {Array.from({ length: Math.min(pagesToShow, maxPages) }, (_, i) => (
              <button
                key={i + 1}
                onClick={() => paginate(i + 1)}
                className={currentPage === i + 1 ? "active" : ""}
              >
                {i + 1}
              </button>
            ))}
            <button
              onClick={() => paginate(currentPage + 1)}
              disabled={currentPage === maxPages}
            >
              Next
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => paginate(maxPages)}
              disabled={currentPage === maxPages}
            >
              Last
            </button>
            <button onClick={downloadAsPDF}>Download</button>
            <button onClick={printTable}>Print</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default ButtonUsage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be a css matter. Try this:
In your css file add the media query @media print and choose what you want to be visible in your printing.  Make sure that the content of the table TableContainer has the targetted id, for example: `id="printable-content"`:
Then in your css

```css
@media print {
  #printable-content {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```